# How do I put two <div>s side-by-side, with the left <div> taking up 100% of the space not taken up by the right <div>?

Tags: html, css

I've got a basic issue. Two `<div>`s side-by-side, the left `<div>` needs to be able to have a 'flexible' width, as in when the `<div>` on the right isn't displayed, the left `<div>` will then stretch to 100%.

My code currently is as follows, which doesn't fulfil the above requirement.

```
<html>
        <head>
        <style>
        #container {
                display: block;
        }

        #box-left {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: red;
                float: left;
        }

        #box-right {
                width: 15%;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: blue;
                float: right;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <div id="container">
                <div id="box-left"></div>
                <div id="box-right"></div>
        </div>
        <body>

        </body>
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#container {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
#id-right, #id-left {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
#id-left {
  /* no width */
}
#id-right {
  width: 15%;
}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work in IE6, but apart from that it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `max-width:100%;` for 'box-left' ?

Comment: max-width doesn't work, if the width doesn't stretch at all to the right (as is the case with floats).

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse the order in which `#box-left` and `#box-right` appear in the HTML, and remove the `width` property from `#box-left` in the CSS, it should work how you describe:

```
#box-left {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        float: left;
}

...

<div id="container">
        <div id="box-right"></div>
        <div id="box-left"></div>
</div>
```

You might not want that source order though, in which case `<table>`s (or the CSS equivalent) are the only HTML/CSS layout system that allows for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

would setting the width of the left div to the rest of the space you have. So since your box-right is 15% make your box-left to 85%

here is code:

```
#container {
                display: block;
        }

        #box-left {
                width: 85%;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: red;
                float: left;
        }

        #box-right {
                width: 15%;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: blue;
                float: right;
        }
```